# Integrating setup.py with Makefile to run tests

Tags: python, testing, makefile, code-coverage, packaging

I used to run the tests for my packages from the Makefile as a way to perform three tasks in one: setup a virtual environment, install requirements and call the testing suite with the corresponding arguments:

```
test: venv
  env/bin/pip install -r test_requirements.txt
  env/bin/nosetests --rednose --with-coverage --cover-pagacke my_module
```

Then I read that requirements.txt files are discouraged in favor of setup.py, so I modified the setup.py file aiming to get the same result:

```
setup(
    ...
    tests_require=['nose', 'rednose', 'coverage'],
    test_suite=['nose.collector'])
```

Now I could change the Makefile with

```
test: venv
    coverage run --source=my_module/ setup.py test
```

But that requires installing the testing dependencies before running the setup.py file. I'm also not sure how to include other arguments such as rednose. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: "perform three tasks in one: setup a virtual environment, install requirements and call the testing suite" — This is exactly what [tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io) is for.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with requirements.txt, they are not discouraged. setup.py and requirements.txt just have different [roles](https://caremad.io/posts/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/). Having said I also recommend to use tox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tox is good and all, but here's how to do it without having to install any  other package beforehand.

List the testing dependencies as `setup_requires` instead of `tests_require` in the **setup.py** file

```
setup(
    setup_requires=['nose', 'rednose', 'coverage'],
    install_requires=[]  # fill in other arguments as usual
)
```

Optionally add test parameters to the **setup.cfg** file.

```
[nosetests]
rednose=1
detailed-errors=1
with-coverage=1
cover-package=server
cover-xml=1
verbosity=2
```

Run the tests with the following command

```
python setup.py nosetests
```

Source: http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/commands.html

Comment: **coverage** works fine in **tests_require** but **rednose** needs to be in **setup_requires**. Do you know why is that?